# What does TFS do when you get using a label which only affects some files?

Tags: tfs

We're wanting to port our old VSS DBs to TFS. One thing we do in the current build process is allow passing a label name which is used when getting the source code from VSS. We don't have a full TFS project yet and I'm not sure old labels are imported so testing is a problem.

If you try to get from tfs using a label which only applies to certain files/subdirs, will TFS  get the labelled versions where they exist and the latest versions otherwise, or will it do something annoying like delete all the working copies which are not labelled? The docs I looked at didn't make this very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on my box, I created a new label (L1) for a folder (F1) within my branch (B1). From TFS I got the latest of the folders (F1, F2, F3 within B1) and I verified that my local box has all the files.

Now I right clicked on the branch (B1) and got the label (L1). This caused the folders F2 and F3 to be deleted and I was left with only the folder F1 locally.

Now From TFS I got the latest of the folders (F1, F2, F3 within B1) again and I verified that my local box has all the files. This time I right clicked the folder F1 and then got the label L1. This time I got the L1 version of the folder F1 and the other folder F2, F3 were not deleted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to make sure I understood that right - in summary you _have_ to explicitly get the labelled version _only_ for folders/files which have that label, if you want to keep the rest of the files?

Comment: Yup exactly, that's what I found in my POC.